# Regular Expresion in spark

Tags: regex, apache-spark

How to remove bracket in string on spark
All value in column is like
`[8a65ddef-9863-43-2121-1211asda]` and i don't know how to remove the first and last bracket.
The expected value is `8a65ddef-9863-43-2121-1211asda`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may do a replacement on the pattern `^\[|\]$`:

```
regexp_replace('[8a65ddef-9863-43-2121-1211asda]', r'^\[|\]$', '')
```

Comment: on spark i have regexp_replace function
but what regex i shoud put in this function
regexp_replace(col(my_column_with_bracket), "what pattern i should use to remove bracket"))

Comment: Um...doesn't my answer tell you that?

Comment: ok i got it:
this is working regexp_replace(col(my_column_with_bracket), "\[(.*?)\]", 1)